# Problema Alcance de variable en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema muy extraño de alcance de variable, estoy usando la función setInterval() y hay una variable que no tiene alcance en esta función.

**este es mi codigo:**

```
cantidad = 14;    
nItemCart= 14;
interval=[];
restarCantidad(cantidad, nItemCart){
    if (cantidad > 0) {
      cantidad--;
      this.nItemCart--;

      console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, this.nItemCart); // en esta linea si reconoce la variable
      this.interval.push(setInterval(function (nItemCart) {
        if (cantidad > 0) {
          cantidad--;
          console.log(nItemCart, this.nItemCart); // en esta linea no reconoce la variable
          nItemCart--;
          console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart, this.nItemCart); // en esta otra linea tampoco reconoce la variable
        }
      }, 150));
    }


this.restarCantidad(this.cantidad, this.nItemCart);
```

el resultado por consola es el siguiente:

```
estoy restando 13 13
undefined NaN
estoy restando 12 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 11 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 10 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 9 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 8 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 7 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 6 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 5 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 4 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 3 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 2 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 1 NaN NaN
undefined NaN
estoy restando 0 NaN NaN
```

Comment: Tal parece que sólo necesitas copiar el `this` a una variable temporal. Usa el clásico `var self = this;` antes de tu función `push` y dentro de ella usa el `self` que acabas de definir, es decir, `self.nItemCart`.

Comment: Hice varios cambios con self/this a tus variables, revisa si este es el resultado que buscas, ya que no lo especificaste como tal en tu pregunta, por favor. https://jsfiddle.net/lixusrarnavo/5n8hoy36/1/

Comment: Cesar su solución funciono, responde la pregunta y la marco como correcta

Comment: @César su sugerencia funciona, escriba la respuesta a la pregunta para marcarla como correcta

Comment: @DanielEnriqueRodriguezCaste listo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como mencionaba en mis comentarios, lo puedes solucionar usando una variable temporal de esta manera antes de función `push`:

```
cantidad = 14;    
nItemCart= 14;
interval=[];
restarCantidad(cantidad, nItemCart){
    if (cantidad > 0) {
      cantidad--;
      this.nItemCart--;

      console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, this.nItemCart);

      var self = this;

      this.interval.push(setInterval(function (nItemCart) {
        if (cantidad > 0) {
          cantidad--;
          console.log(nItemCart, self.nItemCart);
          nItemCart--;
          console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart, self.nItemCart);
        }
      }, 150));
    }


this.restarCantidad(this.cantidad, this.nItemCart);
```

Como ves, esto es un problema de scope, el uso de `this` cambia cuando lo usas dentro de la función `this.interval.push(...)` y para poder hacer referencia a las variables fuera de esta función he definido `self`.

Answer (score 3):

Ejecuto todas respuestas y ningunas funcionan, me sigue dado el error de `NaN` y `undefined`.

Lo que en realidad pasa es que tienes definida la variable `nItemCart` 3 veces y en contexto diferente.

Por ejemplo:

```
this.interval.push(setInterval(function (nItemCart) { 
    //... 
})
```

Nunca le pasas el valor all callback para el parametro `nItemCart` a la funcion `setInterval`. Deberia de ser asi:

```js
   var nItemCart = 9;
setInterval(function(){console.log(arguments)},300, nItemCart);
```

Despues esto:

```
this.interval.push(setInterval(function (nItemCart) {  
    this.nItemCart
    //..
})
```

`this` en este caso se refiere al contexto actual en el que se ejecuta la funcion, no el parametro por eso te dara `undefined`.

Este seria el resultado final

```js
cantidad = 5;    
nItemCart= 5;
interval=[];
function restarCantidad(cantidad, nItemCart){
    if (cantidad > 0) {
      cantidad--;
      this.nItemCart--;

      console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart); // en esta linea si reconoce la variable
      this.interval.push(setInterval(function (nItemCart) {
        if (cantidad > 0) {
          cantidad--;
          console.log(nItemCart, nItemCart); // en esta linea no reconoce la variable
          nItemCart--;
          console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart, this.nItemCart); // en esta otra linea tampoco reconoce la variable
        }
      }, 150, nItemCart));
    }
}

this.restarCantidad(this.cantidad, this.nItemCart);
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema son los this (todos) o eso parece por lo poco que pusiste.
Quita los this de la función anónima, te diría que quites todos pero no conozco el resto del código

```
cantidad = 14;    
nItemCart= 14; //No tiene el this, se maneja como variable local no como propiedad
interval=[]; //No tiene el this, se maneja como variable local no como propiedad

//Esta funcion no tiene el this entonces esta dentro de un contexto global
restarCantidad(cantidad, nItemCart){
    if (cantidad > 0) {
      cantidad--;

      //El this hace referencia al contexto de restarCantidad
      //La variable nItemCart que le pasas como argumento será distinta a ésta aunque tengan el mismo nombre
      this.nItemCart--; 

      //Lo mismo, el this hace referencia al contexto de restarCantidad, la variable que le pasas como asgumento será distinta
      console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, this.nItemCart); 
      //El this.interval no es el mismo que declaraste fuera de la funcion ya que el this hace referencia al contexto de restarCantidad
      this.interval.push(setInterval(function (nItemCart) { //<- Esto es una función anónima*
        if (cantidad > 0) {
          cantidad--;
          //El this de this.nItemCart hace referencia al contexto de la función anónima* creada en el setInterval
          console.log(nItemCart, this.nItemCart); 
          nItemCart--;
          //Lo mismo, el this hace referencia al contexto de la función anónima
          console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart, this.nItemCart); // en esta otra linea tampoco reconoce la variable
        }
      }, 150));
    }

//Como no está el código completo no se el this a quien hace referencia 
//pero es diferente al restarCantidad de arriba, ya que el de arriba no tiene un this entonces su contexto es el global
this.restarCantidad(this.cantidad, this.nItemCart);
```

**EDITO**
Esa no era la solución era el porque no funcionaba tu código
Corrigiendolo sería así

```js
cantidad = 14;    
nItemCart= 14; //No tiene el this, se maneja como variable local no como propiedad
interval=[]; //No tiene el this, se maneja como variable local no como propiedad

//Esta funcion no tiene el this entonces esta dentro de un contexto global
function restarCantidad(){
    if (cantidad > 0) {
      cantidad--;  

      //El this hace referencia al contexto de restarCantidad
      //La variable nItemCart que le pasas como argumento será distinta a ésta aunque tengan el mismo nombre
      nItemCart--; 

      //Lo mismo, el this hace referencia al contexto de restarCantidad, la variable que le pasas como asgumento será distinta
      console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart); 
      //El this.interval no es el mismo que declaraste fuera de la funcion ya que el this hace referencia al contexto de restarCantidad
      this.interval.push(setInterval(function () { //<- Esto es una función anónima*
        if (cantidad > 0) {
          cantidad--;
          //El this de this.nItemCart hace referencia al contexto de la función anónima* creada en el setInterval
          console.log(nItemCart, nItemCart); 
          nItemCart--;
          //Lo mismo, el this hace referencia al contexto de la función anónima
          console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart, nItemCart); // en esta otra linea tampoco reconoce la variable
        }
      }, 150));
    }
}
//Como no está el código completo no se el this a quien hace referencia 
//pero es diferente al restarCantidad de arriba, ya que el de arriba no tiene un this entonces su contexto es el global
restarCantidad();
```

Comment: Sigue fallando http://jsbin.com/yuwaveroqi/edit?js,console,output

Comment: ¿Por qué votas como no útil? Yo te dije porque no funcionaba en comentarios, no la solución ! Edito para que ejecute tu código ya corregido

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es un problema de concepto, el this se refiere al ámbito que lo usa, por ejemplo, en tu caso el this existe solo en el ambito de cada función, te explico:

```
cantidad = 14;    
nItemCart= 14;
interval=[];
restarCantidad(cantidad, nItemCart){
    if (cantidad > 0) {
      cantidad--;
      this.nItemCart--; //*** Aquí estas usando this para referirte al ambito de la funcion "restarCantidad" hasta el momento todo correcto

      console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, this.nItemCart); // en esta linea si reconoce la variable
      this.interval.push(setInterval(function (nItemCart) {
        if (cantidad > 0) {
          cantidad--;
    //Como ves, la funcion "this.interval.pus" usa un "callback" que es una función anonima, 
//es decir otra función. por lo tanto tiene un ambito propio, esto quiere decir que cuando usas "this" aquí dentro, solo usa el ambito de la función. por eso "this.nItemCart" es diferente al que usas arriba.
          console.log(nItemCart, this.nItemCart); 
          nItemCart--;
          console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart, this.nItemCart); // en esta otra linea tampoco reconoce la variable
        }
      }, 150));
    }


this.restarCantidad(this.cantidad, this.nItemCart);
```

Te lo explico con un ejemplo más sencillo.

```
// función sencilla que recibe una variable a
function funcion1(a){
    // Declaras una variable dentro de la función.
    let variable = 10;

    // imprimo el valor de la variable, en este caso "this" hace referencia al ambito de la función "funcion1";
    console.log(this.variable); //Imprime 10

    setTimeout(function(){
      let variable = 30;
      // imprimo el valor de la variable, en este caso "this" hace referencia al ambito de la función anónima del "SetTimeout"
      console.log(this.variable);   //imprime 30;    
    },1000);

    // otra forma para poder enteder mejor, cuando se llama a funcion2 se crea un ambito solo para esa funcion y es la que usa el "this":
    setTimeout(funcion2 ,1000);

}

// funcion sencilla que se llama desde el "setTimeout"
function funcion2(){
  let variable = 50;
  // imprimo el valor de la variable, en este caso "this" hace referencia al ambito de la función funcion2
  console.log(this.variable);   //imprime 50;    
}
```

Ahora te propongo la forma como te podría funcionar:

```
//Aquí estas declarando las variables de forma global (a menos que este código esté dentro de alguna funcion o clase);
// Esto queire decir que se puede acceder a estas variables desde caulquier función.
    cantidad = 14;    
    nItemCart= 14;
    interval=[];


    // Según entiendo, intentas modificar las variables definidas arriba, por eso no creo necesario que las pases como parametro
    // Ya que como expliqué arriba se pueden acceder desde cualquier función.

    function restarCantidad(){
        if (cantidad > 0) {
          cantidad--;
          // no necesitamos usar el "this";
          nItemCart--;

          console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart); // No usamos el "this"
          interval.push(setInterval(function () { // no recibe parametros
            if (cantidad > 0) {
              cantidad--;
              console.log(nItemCart, nItemCart);  //No usamos el "this"
              nItemCart--;
              console.log("estoy restando", cantidad, nItemCart, nItemCart); // sin el "this";
            }
          }, 1500));
        }
}


    // LLalamos la funcion sin parametros.
    this.restarCantidad();
```

si quieres entender un poco mas acerca del contexto de las funciones, te dejo algo de documentación
para que lo pongas en practica

[https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this](http://%22this%22%20en%20JavaScript)

Comment: Lo que escribes no funciona. Disculpa que vote como no util, pero tu respuesta demuestra que siquiera lo probaste. Por si tienes duda, mira tu respuesta aqui: http://jsbin.com/leqikulata/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Tienes razón no lo había probado, ya hice las correcciones correspondientes.
Gracias.

Comment: @EinerSantana  podrías por favor quitar la calificación negativa, Gracias.